# Meta property sharing link on whatsapp is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, meta

Until today I did not know how to show an image when sharink a link on whatsapp.
I have this site:

https://vivepuravida.com/propiedad/casa-escazu-41-apartamento-115k/

You can check I have this on the head tag:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://vivepuravida.com/propiedad/casa-escazu-41-apartamento-115k/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Testing sharing">
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="https://image.wasi.co/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJzdGF0aWN3Iiwia2V5IjoiaW5tdWVibGVzXC9ncjgwMjkyMDIxMDEwNjExNDgxNS5qcGciLCJlZGl0cyI6eyJub3JtYWxpc2UiOnRydWUsInJvdGF0ZSI6MCwicmVzaXplIjp7IndpZHRoIjo5NzksImhlaWdodCI6NzQzLCJmaXQiOiJjb250YWluIiwiYmFja2dyb3VuZCI6eyJyIjoyNTUsImciOjI1NSwiYiI6MjU1LCJhbHBoYSI6MX19fX0=">
```

As you can see the og:image is set with another picture took from another site.

But when sharing my website on whatsapp, it only displays my website icon.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing the image to 400×400 and convert to .png or .jpg formats.